# Smarty upgrade don't work only in remote server

Tags: php, smarty

I had upgraded my smarty to v3.
I have a strange thing about this. It throws SmartyCompilerExceptions what is normal because I have the code in v2 format.

I have this on my tpl: `{foreach key=k item=i from=$err}...{/foreach}` and this isn't work in Smarty 3. I will change this, but my problem is:

Smarty throws those errors only in my production server.
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "/www/site/tpl/system.tpl" on line 272 "{foreach key=key item=item from=$content}" - Unexpected "$", expected one of: "identifier"'`
On my home server everything works. 
I have the same apache, php and Smarty on both systems.

How can this be? Why works the old code in my test system with Smarty 3 without throwing errors? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your call to:

```
{foreach key="key" item="item" from=$content}
```

That is, enclose your strings to double quotes. Smarty 3 is more strict when it comes to quoting things

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to `{foreach $content as $i}`, and it works. But I can't figure out, why my old code works on my local server. Why don't throws errors.

Comment: perhaps you're using a different smarty version?

Comment: no, i'm using the same version. I have to upgrade to the newest version on the test and production servers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, because my production server throws an error and my test server don't is that on my production is `mbstring.func_overload` set to 7 and on my test server this is set to 0.

Hope it helps to someone.